# AVPlayerViewControllerでフルスクリーン動画再生時のメモリリーク

Tags: swift, ios, memory-leaks

AVPlayerViewControllerを使用して動画を再生する画面を構築しています。
普通に再生する分には問題ないのですが、
プレイヤーのコントローラの右端にある全画面モードの切り替えボタンから動画を全画面再生に移行し
再度通常のサイズに復帰させると大量のメモリリークが発生します。

手元の環境(Xcode8.0、Swift2.3、iPhone 6s)で以下のようなコードで再現します。

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class MoviePlayViewController: UIViewController {

  var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 240)

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hoge", ofType: "mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    self.playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    self.view.addSubview(self.playerViewController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(self.playerViewController)
    self.playerViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

リークの内容は以下のような感じです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

AVKitのリーク箇所詳細。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実装方法に問題があるのかAVPlayerViewController側の問題なのか判断ができずにいるため、
ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば原因、解決策をご教示いただきたいです。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

こちらでも実機を使って再現しました。AppleのSDKのバグだと思います。https://bugreporter.apple.com から報告することをお勧めします。

なお `var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController` はstrong参照でなくてもいいと思ったのでweakのOptionalにしてみましたが、メモリリークは消えませんでした。

現状でメモリリークを回避するには、AVPlayerViewControllerを使わず自前でAVPlayerLayerを使ってプレイヤーをスクラッチする必要があると思います。

Answer (score 1):

本件、Apple Bug Reporterから報告していたのですが、
重複扱いでクローズするよ、という返信が今日ありました。

重複先は「Duplicate of 29519477 (Closed)」となっていたので、
多分解決されたのだと思います。次のリリースには入るのかな？

以上、情報共有でした。